# Value at risk vba

Tags: excel, vba, time-series, montecarlo, scenarios

I am running a Monte Carlo simulation with VBA where one variable (call it x) affects the output (call it y). The variables are two time series (x1,x2,...,x10 and y1,y2,...,y10).

I just implemeted the code to run 200 simulations at once and get the average values for x and y for each year. I also added a piece of code to detect the worst case based on the sum of y1,..,y10 and paste that in a separate tab.

What I would like to achieve in the same tab is finding the 99% worst case (which over 100 simulations would be the 99th, over 200 would be the 198th, and so on)
While with the worst case I just compare it to a minimum and get it, I am not sure how to proceed with this, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to run the number of simulations and then determine which ones are the ones you want to call out as being the one percent of cases that are the worst.

How is the data displayed in your workbook? If you could format your ten values (y1,...,y10) could be organised in a row or in a column in a workbook, you could include sequential rows or columns for each simulation and then once all of them have run, you could identify which ones are in the worst one percent.